# Conjure-up Exception: Could not determine Juju version

Tags: juju, conjure-up

I am trying to run conjure-up and i keep getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/133/bin/conjure-up", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/snap/conjure-up/133/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/app.py", line 208, in main
    utils.juju_version()))
  File "/snap/conjure-up/133/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/utils.py", line 129, in juju_version
    raise Exception("Could not determine Juju version.")
Exception: Could not determine Juju version.
```

I followed the simple guidline of the documentation running the following:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
conjure-up
```

Can I get any help,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check your juju version:

```
juju version
```

If output is something like this:

```
The program 'juju' can be found in the following packages:
* juju-2.0
* juju-1-default
Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

check your `$PATH` environment variable:

```
echo $PATH
```

If there is no path `/snap/bin` in the variable just add it like this:

```
export PATH="/snap/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/bin/snap:$PATH"
```

Now, i hope, you can run conjure-up without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in a vm with Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS, the only thing needed to fix it was to update the system packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After updating it started properly when running "conjure-up"

Answer (score 1):

I had to install juju from snap to make this work (tried above but did not work).

```
sudo snap install juju --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases where you may have had previous deb installs of juju and/or conjure-up you may need to exit the shell (or logout completely) before the snap version of conjure-up works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message on ubuntu 16.04 i was  able to fix the issue by running:

1. `sudo usermod -a -G lxd <USER>`
2. `newgrp lxd`
3. `conjure-up`